# How to get DateTime value from DataRow in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the date of birth of employees from the `DataRow`s of the `DataTable`, but I'm getting the exception:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Please help me to get the value of type `DateTime` from the `DataRow`. The following is the my code.

```
List employeeList = new List();
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
   DateTime t = DateTime.Now;
   employeeObject.EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt64(dr["empId"]);
   employeeObject.EmployeeFirstName = Convert.ToString(dr["empFirstName"]);
   employeeObject.EmployeeMiddleName = Convert.ToString(dr["empMiddleName"]);
   employeeObject.EmployeeLastName = Convert.ToString(dr["emptLastName"]);
   employeeObject.EmployeeGenderStr = Convert.ToString(dr["empGender"]);
   employeeObject.EmployeeDateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["empDOB"]);
   //employeeObject.EmployeeDateOfBirth = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["empDOB"].ToString().Replace(";", " "), "m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);// DateTime.Parse(dr["empDOB"].ToString());
   // employeeObject.EmployeeDateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["empDOB"].ToString().Replace(";", " "), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN").DateTimeFormat); ;
   employeeObject.EmployeeContactno = Convert.ToDouble(dr["empContactNo"]);
   employeeObject.EmployeeEmailId = Convert.ToString(dr["empEmailId"]);
   employeeObject.EmployeeAddress = Convert.ToString(dr["empAddress"]);
   employeeObject.EmployeeDesignation = Convert.ToString(dr["empDesgnation"]);
   employeeList.Add(employeeObject);
}
```

Comment: What is the format of the string called `EmployeeDateOfBirth`. I mean what's the format of the value you get form the db. I am asking, because I saw that you use the `String`'s method called `Replace`. If you need to make any replace, you should do this, before the use of `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Comment: we need an example how the empDOP is stored in  db ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving a DateTime value from a DataRow (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106204/retrieving-a-datetime-value-from-a-datarow-c)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, EmployeeDateOfBirth is of datetime datatype, empDOP is of type datetime datatype

Comment: Well, what I would do besides using the debugger is add a line like `MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}: {1}", dr["empDOB"].GetType().Name, (dr["empDOB"] == null ? "NULL" : dr["empDOB"].ToString())));` and post what the MessageBox says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this and replace **"yyyy-MM-dd"** with your desired format.

```
 DateTime.ParseExact(dr["empDOB"].toString(), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: What is the logic behind this?

Comment: @shree.pat18 What do you mean?

Comment: We don't know what value he gets in emoDB so we can't tell how to parse it.

Comment: @maszynaz Exactly. OP has not provided any info about the date time format or the actual value that he gets when debugging the code, so why would you propose this as an answer?

Comment: For some reason i edited my answer exactly after my post saying that he should replace "yyyy-dd-MM" with the his desired format. But christiandev edited it :o

Comment: Hi, empDOb is of type DateTime datatype and EmployeeDateOfBirth is also of tyoe datetime datatype

Comment: @Thanos Markou the olution which you have given showing error that DateTime.TryParseExcet nooverload methods doesnot accept 3 Parameters

Comment: @SantoshKumar Try again.

Comment: @ThanosMarkou, I edited the post to wrap the *one liner* onto a second line to make it easier to read than having to scroll!

Comment: @Thanos Markou I am getting exception "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." DataRow value for DoB is '1/1/1990 11:20:30 AM'

Comment: @Thanos Markou  I am getting exception "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." for DateTime.ParseExact(dr["empDOB"].toString(), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture). Hi dr["empDOB"] contains the value of like '1/1/1990 11:20:30 AM' i want to take this value and assign to the object employeeObject.EmployeeDateOfBirth

Comment: @Thanos Markou Its working now thanks for the reply, I am struggling to solve this issue since morning(Hyderabad,INDIA). Once again thank u

Answer (score 5):

```
employeeObject.EmployeeDateOfBirth= Convert.ToDateTime(dr["empDOB"]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
employeeObject.EmployeeDateOfBirth = dr["empDOB"] != null ? 
         (DateTime)dr["empDOB"] : 
          DateTime.MinValue;
```

This will give you the `MinValue` if it's `null`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, it throwing the exception like "Specified cast is not valid." dr["empDOB"] contains the value of like '1/1/1990 11:20:30 AM' i want to tke this value and assign to the object employeeObject.EmployeeDateOfBirth

Comment: @SantoshKumar Can you put a BreakPoint on the line and see what value is actually in `dr["empDOB"]`? Are you sure that it's a `DateTime` value, as you said? If it really is a `DateTime`, you shouldn't get an `InvalidCastException`. (I wonder if it could have something to do with `DBNull` rather than `null`?)

Comment: @Sahuagin Hi, dr["empDOB"] contains the value of like '1/1/1990 11:20:30 AM' i want to take this value and assign to the object employeeObject.EmployeeDateOfBirth

Comment: what datatype is it in the database? (I'm assuming you're getting the data from a DB)

Comment: This sould be the accepted answer. But it sould check for DbNull.Value, because database null values are DbNull-s by the framework.
I can't see why are here so many complicated answers out there. If is's a DateTime, treat it as a DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

Check for null before binding.

From what I can see, am not seeing any check for null and replacing the null with datetime minValue, unless the check is been done within your DB?. I had a similar problem, and that check resolved it.

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["empDOB"])) 
{`employeeObject.EmployeeDateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["empDOB"]);`

}
else
{
  DateTime DOB = DateTime.MinValue;}

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply but DateTime datatype will not have any nulls, it will have min value DateTime.MinValue....and min value is 1/1/1900 00:00:00 as my datatbase table column datatype is DateTime if null value is passed it will take Date.Min value .

Comment: @kachide Hi,  db doesnot have anu null value it contains value 1/1/1990 11::20:00, but it causing the issue

Comment: @ kachidude thanks for reply its working now  with following solutionemployeeObject.EmployeeDateOfBirth = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["empDOB"].ToString(),
 "d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Answer (score 1):

It's a little late, but if someone needs it, try this simple solution.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   if (row["empDOB"] != DBNull.Value)
      item.vytvorena = (DateTime)row["empDOB"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
employeeObject.EmployeeDateOfBirth = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["empDOB"].toString(), 
"d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, it throwing the exception like "Specified cast is not valid." dr["empDOB"] contains the value of like '1/1/1990 11:20:30 AM'  i want to tke this value and assign to the object employeeObject.EmployeeDateOfBirth