# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Tags: c#

I have received this exception when one of my column's data table have null value. Let say I do want to allow null value or something like this, how can I fix this?

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

This is my code.

```
     foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
     row["Effective_Period"] = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Effect_Date_From"].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") 
+ " - " +  Convert.ToDateTime(row["Effect_Date_To"].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
```

In my ds.Table, here is my column

```
----------------------
Effective_Period
---------------------
10/2/2012 - 20/3/2012
---------------------

---------------------

---------------------
```

Comment: What you want to do when the column has `null`?

Comment: you cant convert a null column to datatime that is why you get the error, i suggest you update your stored procedure to handle the nulls so that you wont return any nulls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    DateTime effectiveDateFrom;
    DateTime effectiveDateTo;

    if (!DateTime.TryParse(row["Effect_Date_From"], out effectiveDateFrom)
        effectiveDateFrom = DateTime.MinValue;

    if (!DateTime.TryParse(row["Effect_Date_To"], out effectiveDateTo)
        effectiveDateTo = DateTime.MinValue;

    row["Effective_Period"] = effectiveDateFrom.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - " +  effectiveDateTo.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This is a perfect solution :)

Comment: So why did you remove the answered flag?

Comment: Oh sorry, i pressed the wrong button, didnt realize that

Answer (score 0):

You may want to reflect the nullable option in your C# representation of the DateTime definition:

```
Nullable<DateTime> value;
// or
DateTime? value;
```

Both forms are equivalent.

Ofcourse, when working with the value in C#, you have to define what to do on `null` and you can't rely on some magic `null.ToString()` for your conversions.

You may also want to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106204/retrieving-a-datetime-value-from-a-datarow-c). Essence: use `row.Field<DateTime?>("Effect_Date_From")` to get your nullable `DateTime` from a datarow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow `NULL`, then make the field as `NULLABLE` in your Database table. It will then allow `NULL` values to be inserted without any issues.

Also, if you want to allow a value such as you have shown, you will have to make the field as `nvarchar` since this wont be recognized as a valid `DateTime`.

Another important note, instead of storing like this, you could easily create two separate columns for the from-to period and store `DateTime` values in both respectively. That would also give you the advantage to query data and filter data as per the dates required.

**UPDATE :**

You will also receive this exception if you pass a `NULL` and use `.ToString()`. So make sure you are passing something here, be it a date or a string before using `.ToString()`. And on the backend, you can modify the data type as you prefer.

*A good thing to do here would be implementing a null check before you convert using `.ToString()`.* If its null, you can straightaway pass a `null` and if its not, you can convert the value and then pass that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: in the OP's code, he's trying to operate on nulls. the ToString().

Answer (score 0):

Using `DateTime.TryParse` can help you check if there is an invalid date, and twist your business logic accordingly.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                bool fromIsNull = DBNull.Value.Equals(row["Effect_Date_From"]);
                bool toIsNull = DBNull.Value.Equals(row["Effect_Date_To"]);
                row["Effective_Period"] = (fromIsNull ? string.Empty : Convert.ToDateTime(row["Effect_Date_From"].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
                    + (fromIsNull || toIsNull ? string.Empty : " - " )
                    + (toIsNull ? string.Empty : Convert.ToDateTime(row["Effect_Date_To"].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            }
```

updated the code to accommodate your last comment. that's how you'd hide/show the " - ". but that's all up to how you want to handle the case.

Comment: Hi I have tried your method, it said cannot convert string to bool in this block of code `Convert.ToDateTime(row["Effect_Date_From"].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - " + DBNull.Value.Equals(row["Effect_Date_To"]) `

Comment: updated the code section. I was missing a couple of parenthesis for the precedence of operations.

Comment: I see, thanks for your help. See Kees for the correct answer :)

Comment: I am just curoius about your solution, How will you let say if the effectDateFrom  is null, then just display the effectDateTo without the '-' sign?

Comment: i'd change + " - " + to + (DBNull.Value.Equals(row["Effect_Date_From"]) || DBNull.Value.Equals(row["Effect_Date_To"]) ? "" : " - ") +.

Comment: I've updated the code. I used two booleans this time to make the lines shorter and because each DBNull.Value.Equals is used more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Null doesn't have a ToString() function so if you expect results to be null you have to make sure you won't call a function on it.